# Render a child component in the global app component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I wrote a **dialog component** (global) to show modal dialogs with overlays like popup forms.

Right now the dialog gets **rendered inside the component where it is used**. This leads to **overlapping content**, if there is something with position relative in the html code afterwards.

I want it to be rendered in the root App component at the very end **so I can force the dialog to be always ontop of every other content**.

This is my not working solution:
I tried to use **named slots**, hoping, that they work backwards in the component tree too. Unfortunately they don't seem to do that.

**Anybody a solution how to do it?**

My next idea would be to render with an extra component that is stored in the app component and register the dialogs in the global state. But that solution would be super complicated and looks kinda dirty.

The dialog component:

```
<template v-slot:dialogs>
  <div class="dialog" :class="{'dialog--open': show, 'dialog--fullscreen': fullscreen }">
    <transition name="dialogfade" duration="300">
      <div class="dialog__overlay" v-if="show && !fullscreen" :key="'overlay'" @click="close"></div>
    </transition>
    <transition name="dialogzoom" duration="300">
      <div class="dialog__content" :style="{'max-width': maxWidth}" v-if="show" :key="'content'">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    name: "MyDialog",
    props: {show: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      persistent: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      fullscreen: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      maxWidth: {
        type: String,
        default: '600px'
      }
    },
    data: () => ({}),
    methods: {
      close() {
        if(!this.persistent) {
          this.$emit('close')
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The template of the app component:

```
<template>
  <div class="application">
    <div class="background">
      <div class="satellite"></div>
      <div class="car car-lr" :style="{ transform: `translateY(${car.x}px)`, left: adjustedLRLeft + '%' }" v-for="car in carsLR"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <login v-if="!$store.state.user"/>
      <template v-else>
        <main-menu :show-menu="showMainMenu" @close="showMainMenu = false"/>
        <router-view/>
      </template>
      <notifications/>
      <div class="dialogs"><slot name="dialogs"></slot></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the guys from the [vuetify2 project](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/), I found the solution. The dialog component gets an **ref="dialogContent"** attribute and the magic happens inside the **beforeMount** function.

```
<template>
  <div class="dialog" ref="dialogContent" :class="{'dialog--open': show, 'dialog--fullscreen': fullscreen }">
    <transition name="dialogfade" duration="300">
      <div class="dialog__overlay" v-if="show && !fullscreen" :key="'overlay'" @click="close"></div>
    </transition>
    <transition name="dialogzoom" duration="300">
      <div class="dialog__content" :style="{'max-width': maxWidth}" v-if="show" :key="'content'">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    name: "MyDialog",
    props: {
      show: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      persistent: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      },
      fullscreen: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      maxWidth: {
        type: String,
        default: '600px'
      }
    },
    data: () => ({}),
    methods: {
      close() {
        if (!this.persistent) {
          this.$emit('close')
        }
      }
    },
    beforeMount() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        const target = document.getElementById('dialogs');
        target.appendChild(
          this.$refs.dialogContent
        )
      })
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use portals. These provide a way to move any element to any place in the dom. Checkout the following library:  https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. The content of the component stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can just place the dialog component directly in the app component and handle the dialog logic/which dialog to display in that component?

In case you want to trigger these dialogs from other places in your app, this would would be a good use case for vuex! That, combined with dynamic webpack imports is how I handle this.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work eather. It works for static content, but not for dynamic.

Comment: I will post you an example when I have some time